# Getting the handle of parent winform that hosts a wpf control using element host

Tags: .net, wpf-controls

I have a winform application that hosts a wpf control using element host. when I try to use
Window.GetWindow(this), null is returned. I want the reference to the parent winform.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the WindowInteropHelper class as follows:

```
WpfApplication1.Window1 window = new WpfApplication1.Window1();
WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
helper.Owner = this.Handle;
window.Show();
```

More information in [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/7d11e5ef-5483-4fb9-8ae5-dc60e072e10e) thread